# Difference between a directed cycle and a strongly connected component

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graph, cyclic-graph, strongly-connected-graph

[image: Direced Graoh]

I have this graph.
The SCCs in this Graph are {a, b, e}, {d, g}, and {c, d, h}.
But the cycles in this graph are the same components, right?

So what exactly is the difference between SCCs and directed cycles? Do they only differ in specific cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a directed graph `G(V,E)`:

- A **directed path** is a sequence of vertices in which there is a directed edge pointing from each vertex in the sequence to its successor in the sequence, with no repeated edges.
- A **directed cycle** is a **directed path** (with at least one edge) whose first and last vertices are the same.
- A vertex `w` is **reachable** from a vertex `v` if there exists a **directed path** from `v` to `w`.
- A directed graph is **strongly connected** if every vertex is **reachable** from every other vertex in the graph

  - A corollary of this is that for every pair of vertices `v` and `w` in `G` there is a **directed path** from `v` to `w` and a **directed path** from `w` to `v`.
- A directed graph that is not **strongly connected** consists of a set of **strongly connected components**, which are maximal strongly connected sub-graphs.

  - A corollary of this is that for every pair of vertices `v` and `w` in the strongly connected sub-graph `G'(V',E')` where `V' ⊂ V` and `E' ⊂ E` there is a **directed path** from `v` to `w` and a **directed path** from `w` to `v`.

---

The difference is that:

- A **directed cycle** is a single **directed path** (where the first and last vertices are the same) and cannot have repeated edges;
- A **strongly connected component** is a sub-graph where there is a **directed path** from every vertex in the sub-graph to every other vertex in the sub-graph.

If you have the strongly connected component:

```
 A → B
 ↓ ↖ ↓
 C → D
```

Then there is a **directed path** `C → D → A → B` and a **directed path** `B → D → A → C` but there is no **directed cycle** that contains both `B` and `C` as the edge `D → A` would have to be visited twice in the cycle.

---

Additionally, there is another (technical) difference that if the **directed cycle** visits all the vertices then it is a **strongly connected directed graph** and not a **strongly connected component** (as a component is a strict sub-graph).